# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to create a function that could create nested divs. I've been trying it out on the console but this error just stumps me.

```
function iter(obj){
    if(obj.newArray!==[]){
        for(var i=0;i<obj.newArray.length;i++){
            var psot = document.createElement("div");
            psot.Id = obj.newArray[i].id
            psot.innerHTML = obj.newArray[i].value;
            var dives = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var i=0; i<dives.length;i++){
                if (dives[i].id = obj.id){
                    dives[i].appendChild(psot)
                }
            }
            iter(obj)
        }
    }
}

var comment = {
id:"123", value: "summer",
newArray: [{id:"321", value: "hum", newArray:[]}]
}

var post = document.createElement("div")

post.id = "123"

post.innerHTML = "summer"

iter(comment)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tldr: you are trying to assign one of the elements in `dives` which is a `div` to `psot` which is also a `div` so JS assumes you are trying to append an element to itself.

Comment: And your function call `iter(obj)` within the for loop results in an infinite loop.

Comment: `if (dives[i].id = obj.id)` - that is an assignment, not a comparison. // That whole section seems kinda nonsensical - why you are looping over elements to compare their id, instead of just using `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @AndrewL thanks but why is dives a div to psot when I just created the psot div and didn't assign anything to it? Thanks for the infinite loop note.

Comment: @misorude, thanks. There's my big stupid typo responsible for this. I wanted to use a strict comparison operator not assign it. Thank you.